# 'jury': singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, personal-pronouns, collective-nouns, pronominal-agreement

The jury (takes / take) their seats in the courtroom.

I understand that 'the jury' refers to a singular group but does this apply when it is referred to as a plural in 'their'? Thanks.

Comment: Please see previous related questions on this same site. This has been dealt with before.

Comment: Generally speaking, "jury" is singular (in the US).  Use "members of the jury" to refer to the individuals.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. As I interpret the question, it's whether, in AmE, you can say *"the jury takes their seats"*, or do you have to say *"the jury takes its seats"* or *"the jury take their seats"*, and if so, which?  (In British English, it's clearly *"the jury take their seats"*.) Neither of the supposedly duplicate questions addresses this issue. @Faith: If I'm correct, I'd suggest rewriting the question so it's clear what it's asking. Otherwise, it will get closed as a duplicate of questions that don't actually answer it.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be 'Their jury' but the jury can have 'Their judgement'

The jury, which although is a physical group, is grouped up to being a singular noun, we know it to be more than one, but they are a collective, a single entinty that has to decide as a team an outcome at a court hearing.

Similar to how you have a multitude of sheep, but we don't say 'sheeps' they are a herd, a single group.

Comment: Sheep is singular or plural. Jury is (grammatically) singular; there can be several juries sitting in the same court house. So there is a difference between jury and sheep.

Comment: @fdb - Though in some cases the similarities are substantial.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. But this doesn't answer the question. The OP never asked whether you could say *"their jury"*. I think the question is which of the following is correct: *"the jury take their seats", *"the jury takes their seats"*, or *"the jury takes its seats"*. (And it depends on whether you are speaking AmE or BrE.)